# Получение индекса объекта в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Всем привет! Нужно не столько решение, сколько подсказка. Как получить индекс объекта в массиве типа - [1, 2, 3, 4] - понятно. 
Не могу понять, как получить индекс объекта вот в таком массиве:

```
var arrayId = [

    {id: 12},
    {id: 12},
    {id: 12},
    {id: 123},
    {id: 126},
    {id: 1},
    {id: 15},
    {id: 33}

];
```

Или, если есть уже ответ, то киньте ссылку, ибо не нашел.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: _Как получить индекс объекта в массиве типа - [1, 2, 3, 4] - понятно_ - и как например?

Comment: @Grundy мне кажется, что он хочет получить индекс по значению поля

Comment: Обязательно найдется кто-то, кто вместо ответа будет задавать вопрос.
Допустим через indexOf, я не могу сообразить, как его применять в таком массиве, как я написал

Comment: абсолютно так же. Нет никакой разницы

Comment: ОК. Пойдем простым путем. Есть массив объектов, как получить индекс конкретного объекта?

Comment: Grundy, пример можешь написать? я пока не догнал

Comment: `arrayId.indexOf(obj)`

Comment: лады. obj - это конкретный объект?

Comment: @Matvey, да, объект из массива

Comment: вот в том то и суть, я не понимаю что нужно указать вместо obj или какое значение он должен получить, чтобы узнать индекс например вот этого объекта - {id: 126}

Comment: @Matvey, как заполняется массив? и как определяешь индекс какого объекта надо искать?

Comment: конкретно в данном случае это вот такой массив как написан, это все данные. есть функция function somName(arr, idx){}, в которой все и происходит, а определяю по параметру idx через вызов - someName(someArray, 126); посредством if и сравнения item.id после перебора forEach'ем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Весь фокус в том, что в массиве хранятся не сами объекты, а указатели на них и `indexOf` сравнивает именно указатели. Если мы сконструируем два объекта с одинаковыми полями, то это будут разные объекты

```js
var obj1 = {id: 1};
var obj2 = {id: 1};
console.log(obj1 == obj2);  // false
```

поэтому Вам придется пробежаться в цикле по всему массиву и самостоятельно сравнить объект с каждым элементом массива. Или, как подсказал @Grundy, использовать метод `findIndex` c callback-функцией

При этом, если Вы не будете конструировать новый объект, а предварительно добудете его из массива, то будет работать и `indexOf`

```js
var arrayId = [
  {id: 12},
  {id: 12},
  {id: 12},
  {id: 123},
  {id: 126},
  {id: 1},
  {id: 15},
  {id: 33}
];

function indexObj(AObj) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayId.length; i++) {
    if (arrayId[i].id == AObj.id)
      return i;
  }
  return -1;
}

console.log(arrayId.indexOf({id: 1}));
console.log(indexObj({id: 1}));
var obj = arrayId[2];
console.log(arrayId.indexOf(obj));

console.log(
  arrayId.findIndex(
    function (AEl) {
      return AEl.id == this.id;
    },
    {id: 1}
  )
);
```

Comment: Угу, кажется понял, сейчас попробую. Спасибо!

Comment: а еще [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться парой функций:

- [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) - выбираем только соответствующие объекты
- [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) - получаем индекс первого из найденных

```js
var arrayId = [
  {id: 12},
  {id: 12},
  {id: 12},
  {id: 123},
  {id: 126},
  {id: 1},
  {id: 15},
  {id: 33}
];

function find(list, id) {
  var ok = list.filter(a => a.id === id);
  if (!ok.length) return -1;
  return list.indexOf(ok[0]);
}

console.log(find(arrayId, 12));
console.log(find(arrayId, 1));
console.log(find(arrayId, 126));
```

*В этом решении выполняется лишний проход по массиву по сравнению с самостоятельной выборкой в цикле.*